# HttpWebRequest - payload error

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

```
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + GetAccessTokenBeta());
Request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
Request.Method = "POST";
Request.ContentType = "application/xml";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string xml = getXml(tabletype, values.ToArray());
    streamWriter.Write(xml);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

try
{
    using (WebResponse response = Request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {

        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    Core.ShowError("Error connecting to the webservice." + "\r\n" + resp);
}
```

I have confirmed that the endpoint and XML work using Postman, but I am running into this issue in C#.

Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream

Comment: Is "Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream" part of the error message? Where is it failing? It's all quite unclear...

Comment: That line is the error message, it fails at 
"using (WebResponse response = Request.GetResponse())"
right inside the try.

Comment: Sounds like the error is on the server side - is it a Mule server, by any chance? Searching for that error message gives plenty of hits for Mule.